# Executing wmi.Registry.EnumKey gives type mismatch error

Tags: python, registry, wmi

I was trying to lookup all the subkeys under a particular registry key using wmi.Registry.EnumKey() . But it keeps on throwing type mismatch error. I used the below code snippet :

```
import _winreg
import wmi
r = wmi.Registry ()
result, names = r.EnumKey (hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,sSubKeyName=r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
```

Error observed:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in module
>   File"build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\wmi.py", line 431, in **call**
>
> handle_com_error ()
>
> File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
>
> raise klass (com_error=err)
>
> wmi.x_wmi: x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception
>   occurred.', (0,u'SWbemProperty', u'Type mismatch ', None, 0,
>   -2147217403), None)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a 64bit python interpreter? I had a the same issue, it turns out it doesn't like the _winreg values, so just override them with the Windows registry hive constants as seen winreg.h; you can find a copy below:
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/bin/MinGW/include/winreg.h

```
import wmi
HKLM = 0x80000002
r = wmi.Registry()
result, names = r.EnumKey (hDefKey=HKLM,sSubKeyName=r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
```

Comment: I checked my code on 32-bit version and it was working. But I can not run it on a 64-bit version. I even replaced the winreg.h file, but I still face the `Unexpected COM Error`. @jcannell